# How to use multithreading in this python code?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I am trying to use multithreading in a code written in python-flask. Such that, if I try to run this code for multiple users, the process should be parallel.

**This is my code**

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def getExtention():
    if(lang == 'python'):
        # Run a code which will compile and run user's python code and show the output of the user's code
    elif(lang == 'java'):
        # Run a code which will compile and run user's java code and show the output of the user's code
    else:
        # Run the code for some other lang. 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

> What is happening here is, if one user will choose python lang, a specific code will run in background. 
>   Similarly, if another user would choose java, a code will run in background. So the processes should be run in background. They should not wait each other to be finished.

***Please help me to use multithreading here so that the processes will run parallelly***

Comment: You can call your codes with request method in threading. But these kind of requests my fail and lock a thread, so not recommend to use. Use threading (asynchronous programming) for small snippets like calculations, in and out processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should use Evelent or CherryPy Server for your app start.

```
import cherrypy

from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
    # Mount the application
    cherrypy.tree.graft(app, "/")

    # Set the configuration of the web server
    cherrypy.config.update({
        'log.screen': True,
        'server.socket_port': app.config['PORT'],
        'server.socket_host': '::',
        'server.thread_pool': 30,
        'server.shutdown_timeout': 1
    })
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cherrypy.engine.stop()
```

Here app is python directory and in app/**init** file, you can create your flask app.